# How to use std::function as a template

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to the `std::function` concept.

I need to use `std::function` in following way

I have a class as follows

```
class A(string ,bool, string, std::function<void()>)
```

here the `std::function<void()>` should take different parameters from different objects.
The parameters will be basically different types of enumerations

for example

```
1)A a(string ,bool, string, std::function<void(enum xyz)>)
2)A b(string ,bool, string, std::function<void(enum abc)>)
3)A c(string ,bool, string, std::function<void(enum efg)>)
```

I want to know how should i structure the `std::function` in class A so that i can pass different enumerations as parameter to the class A objects

Comment: How do you want to use the `std::function` ?

Comment: A class with parameters? You mean constructor, right?

Comment: As a template? What

Comment: @Jarod42::i dont know how should i use std::function here. please suggest how can i use

Comment: @shadowlif::yes you are right.contructor

Comment: @user5222584 Chad provided now the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a template type as the `std::function` parameter.  Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo(std::function<void(T)> f) : f_{f} {}

   void call(T in) { f_(in); }

private:
   std::function<void(T)> f_;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<double> fd{[] (double d) { std::cout << d << '\n'; }};
    fd.call(34.2);

    Foo<std::string> fs{[] (std::string s) { std::cout << s << '\n'; }};
    fs.call("Test!");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
34.2
Test!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this will help

Comment: @user5222584 if and when someone solves your problem, click on the checkmark to mark it as solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your question, this is how you need to use the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional> //Need to include for std::function use

using namespace std;

//Declare the ENUM here.
enum ePat {xyz=1,abc,efg,mno};
enum ePat_second {def=1,ghi,jkl,opq};


//utility function you want to pass to std function
template <typename T>
void print(T e)
{

}

template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:

    //Constructore with std function as one of the argument
    A(string ,bool , string, std::function<void(T)>)
    {


    }

};

int main()
{
    //Declare your std function types.
     std::function<void(ePat)> xyz_display = print<ePat>;
     std::function<void(ePat_second)> def_display = print<ePat_second>;


    //Pass it to the object.
    A<ePat> a("abc" ,true, "abc",xyz_display);
    A<ePat_second> b("def" ,true, "def",def_display);
}
```

Comment: so i dont have an definate enum to be used across all the objects